# Product edit broken after upgrade from 2.0.7 to 2.1

Tags: magento2, product, admin, javascript

I've just upgraded my Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1 and I getting some errors while trying to edit any product.

The strange thing is that it only **happens with Chrome** (v52.0.2743.116), Firefox is working fine.

Here is what I get:

[image: Screenshot]

And here are the Javascript errors I get:

```
jquery.js:7759 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefinedval @ jquery.js:7759(anonymous function) @ rules.js:664validate @ validator.js:18(anonymous function) @ validator.js:40_.some._.any @ underscore.js:250validator @ validator.js:39validate @ abstract.js:245handleChanges @ qty-validator-changer.js:25setNested @ objects.js:43nested @ objects.js:117set @ element.js:301updateValue @ links.js:57setLink @ links.js:144(anonymous function) @ links.js:160_resolveRequest @ registry.js:413_addRequest @ registry.js:380get @ registry.js:224transfer @ links.js:157setLinks @ links.js:200initLinks @ element.js:182initialize @ element.js:103(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:109_super @ wrapper.js:106initialize @ abstract.js:50(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:109UiClass @ class.js:49initComponent @ layout.js:66fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ layout.js:59execCb @ require.js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774(anonymous function) @ require.js:991(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ mixins.js:106execCb @ require.js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774(anonymous function) @ require.js:991(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ mixins.js:106execCb @ require.js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170completeLoad @ require.js:1544onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function (){return hasAddons() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return elementTmpl }"
Message: elementTmpl is not definedtemplate @ VM13853:3init @ knockout.js:5023(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:2989ignore @ knockout.js:1249(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:2988arrayForEach @ knockout.js:151applyBindingsToNodeInternal @ knockout.js:2974applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2854applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2836ko.applyBindingsToDescendants @ knockout.js:3052ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved @ knockout.js:4004evaluateImmediate @ knockout.js:1737ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable @ knockout.js:1946init @ knockout.js:3988(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:2989ignore @ knockout.js:1249(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:2988arrayForEach @ knockout.js:151applyBindingsToNodeInternal @ knockout.js:2974applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2854applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2836applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2863applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2836applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:2863ko.applyBindings @ knockout.js:3065_super @ wrapper.js:73applyBindings @ bound-nodes.js:116(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:78(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:4862invokeForEachNodeInContinuousRange @ knockout.js:4813activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray @ knockout.js:4860executeTemplate @ knockout.js:4908ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhen @ knockout.js:4950evaluateImmediate @ knockout.js:1737evaluatePossiblyAsync @ knockout.js:1677notifySubscribers @ knockout.js:1103observable.valueHasMutated @ knockout.js:1300observable @ knockout.js:1285(anonymous function) @ engine.js:54fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3263fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ loader.js:97fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ loader.js:96execCb @ require.js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774(anonymous function) @ require.js:991(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ text.js:149xhr.onload @ text.js:112
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return elems }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return !$data.additionalForGroup }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return visible() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return element.input_type !='checkbox'|| element.input_type !='radio' }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return $parent.fieldTemplate }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return hasAddons() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return elementTmpl }"
Message: elementTmpl is not defined
```

Yep, **I already disabled all the custom modules** and **custom Chrome extensions** but it does not fix.

I tracked down the error to the `validator.js` for qty field, is there anyone with the same issue?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Sure, tried it several times... That's the weirdest bug I have ever seen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering by myselft. It was a proxy cache issue.Working fine now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/72792)

Comment: I'm the author... I'm saying it was a proxy issue, not a Magento issue.